# How to derive an proof for this infinite square root equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, recreational-mathematics, functional-equations

Here is continuous square root, namely:

**$\sqrt {1 + a \sqrt {1+b \sqrt {1+c\sqrt {1 +...}}}}$**= any integer

Find $a,b,c,d,e,f,...$ in general

Uh, very interesting algebra pre-calculus problem, yet very challenging.

I know part of the answer but doesn't know how to start working on this problem.

The original problem is to prove **$\sqrt {1 + 2 \sqrt {1+3 \sqrt {1+4\sqrt {1 +...}}}}$**$=3$

However,i am curious on how to prove that we have finite or prove that we have infinite number of answer that satisfy the equation

Comment: are all of those variables integers?

Comment: @Asimov - List all possible answer in different forms (yep, it could be the integers.)

Comment: Surely $a = 8, b = c = d = ... = 0$ works fine.

Comment: Ok, so you want all sets of answers, not one set that falls under the integer constraint.

Comment: a=2,b=3,c=4,c=5,d=6... work also

Comment: This seems to me as a horribly broad question. Now I'm very curious as to what "the answer" was given as.

Comment: $a = b = c = \cdots = 8/3$ also works...

Comment: @achillehui - Do you know all answer that satisfy this?

Comment: @Victor, I don't know. If you don't put any restriction on $a,b,c,\ldots$, there are infinitely many solutionw. Even for integer solutions, I'm not sure their numbers is finite. In any event, other integer solutions are $(a,b,c,d,\ldots) = (4,1,4,1,4,1,\ldots)$, $(2,5,2,5,\ldots)$, $(1,21,1,21,\ldots)$.

Comment: @achillehui - What would you suggest to impose restriction on this problem?

Comment: @Victor, the most natural restriction is requiring the numbers to be integers.

Comment: @achillehui - I am curious about are you a college professor?

Comment: Your original problem is a well known problem from Ramanujan. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Infinitely_nested_radicals

Comment: @Victor, No. I'm just an amateur. In any event, another integer solution $(a,b,c,\ldots) = (2,3,8, 2, 3, 8)$. For this problem, there are some interesting questions one can ask. e.g. 1) are there infinite many integer solutions? 2) are there other non-periodic integer solutions which show some sort of pattern like the one in original problem.

Comment: @achillehui - Thanks to user2345215, we finally have a general solution

Comment: @user2345215 - Appreciate again

Comment: @Victor, user2345215 link contains one solution whose RHS is $3$. In your question, is RHS fixed to $3$ or you allow other integer too???

Comment: @achillehui - You found something interesting?

Comment: @Victor there are infinite many periodic solutions. look at my answer which contains one family of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really should be a comment but it is too long.

There are infinitely many periodic solution which returns $3$.

Let $g(x)$ be the function $x^2-1$ and 
$$g^{\circ n}(x) = \underbrace{g(g(\ldots g(g(}_{n \text{ times}}x))\ldots))$$
be the function obtained by composing $g(x)$ with itself for $n$ times.

For any even $n = 2k \ge 2$, it is easy to check $g^{\circ 2k}(3)$ is divisible by $3$. One can verify

$$(a,b,c,d\ldots) = (\; \underbrace{1, 1, \ldots, 1}_{(2k-1) \text{ times}}, g^{\circ 2k}(3)/3,\; \underbrace{\ldots}_{\text{ just repeat previous pattern}} )$$

provides a periodic solution of length $n$. The first few examples, are

- $n = 2$, $(a,b,\ldots) = (1,21, 1,21, \ldots )$.
- $n = 4$, $(a,b,\ldots) = (1,1,1,5248341, 1,1,1,5248341, \ldots )$.
- $n = 6$, $(a,b,\ldots) = (1,1,1,1,1, 20485753507127298001376466261, \ldots )$.

Answer (score 1):

Copying from Wikipedia in case of losing the data

Ramanujan posed this problem to the 'Journal of Indian Mathematical Society':

$? = \sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3 \sqrt{1+\cdots}}}. \, $

This can be solved by noting a more general formulation:

: $? = \sqrt{ax+(n+a)^2 +x\sqrt{a(x+n)+(n+a)^2+(x+n) \sqrt{\mathrm{\cdots}}}}$

Setting this to F(x) and squaring both sides gives us:$

: $F(x)^2 = ax+(n+a)^2 +x\sqrt{a(x+n)+(n+a)^2+(x+n) \sqrt{\mathrm{\cdots}}}$

Which can be simplified to:

: $F(x)^2 = ax+(n+a)^2 +xF(x+n) $

It can then be shown that:

: $F(x) = {x + n + a}$

So, setting ''a'' =0, ''n'' = 1, and ''x'' = 2:

: $3= \sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3 \sqrt{1+\cdots}}}$

Ramanujan stated this radical in his lost notebook
$\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5-\cdots}}}}}}}=\frac{2+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{15-6\sqrt{5}}}{2}$

Comment: What page on wiki?